# No logro agrupar comprobantes con group by

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla ticket en MySQL, el cliente puede pagar un poco en tarjeta y otra parte en efectivo. Para eso tengo una tabla movimientos con el idtipomovimiento que lleva a otra tabla (tarjeta, efectivo,cuenta corriente,etc).Pero cuando quiero consultar con group by me devuelve los ticket una vez pero solo me muestra el efectivo entregado:

```
   $query="SELECT * from ticket left join tipocomprobante on 
   tipocomprobante.idtipocomp=ticket.idtipocomp left join cliente on 
   ticket.idc=cliente.idcliente left join movimiento on movimiento.idticket=ticket.idticket 
    WHERE cajero=".$idcajero." AND sesion=".$idsesion." group by ticket.idticket;";
```

He probado la consulta en phpMyAdmin y no devuelve los movimientos de tarjeta:

```
  CREATE TABLE `movimiento` (
  `idmov` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipomov` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `importe` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idticket` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idcliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idsesion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `idticket` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vuelto` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idtipocomp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cae` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechavto` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cajero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pago` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE `tipomov` (
  `idtipomov` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Edito la pregunta.:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo esa tabla donde muestro los movimiento de la sesión. Ahi la idea es que aparezcan todos los tickets, con el monto abonado en efectivo, y el monto con tarjeta de débito o crédito.
Como veran genera 2 renglones en la tabla para un mismo ticket, yop quisiera tener cada ticket en un solo renglon.
De lo contrario tendria que modificar la estructura de la tabla ticket y agregar directamente el monto de efectivo y tarjeta. Y luego comprobar si son distintos de 0.

Comment: Qué es tipomov y qué es tipocomp?

Comment: tipomov es el tipo de movimiento(tarjeta,efectivo,etc) y tipocomp es el tipocomprobante(factura a factura b, simple,etc)

Comment: Quieres mostrar cada movimiento pero quieres agrupar por ticket. ¿No es como una condición difícil de cumplir? O usas funciones de agrupación en el monto (y pierdes de vista los movimientos) o transpones los datos y muestras una fila con el ticket y cada valor por movimiento, o no agrupas por ticket, pero todo al tiempo, ¿no es como extraño?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `group by` te va a ocultar info porque agrupas por el ticket sin usar funciones de agregación en los demás datos; el motor no sabe qué debe mostrarte, así que te muestra la primera fila de cada ticket en el conjunto.

Digamos que estas son las tablas y datos de ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE `movimiento` (
  `idmov` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tipomov` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `importe` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idticket` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idcliente` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idsesion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
);
insert into movimiento
values
(1, 1, 123.45, 1, 1, 1, now() ),
(2, 2, 22.44, 1, 1, 1, now());

CREATE TABLE `ticket` (
  `idticket` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vuelto` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hora` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idtipocomp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idc` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cae` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `fechavto` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cajero` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sesion` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pago` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
); 
insert into ticket
values
(1, 'fecha', 145.89, 0.0, 'hora', 1, 123, 'cae', now(), 333, 1, 'pago');

CREATE TABLE `tipomov` (
  `idtipomov` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
); 
insert into tipomov
values
(1, 'efectivo'),
(2, 'cheque');
```

Tengo un ticket, dos movimientos, cada uno de un tipo. Quité los join con los clientes y comprobantes porque parecen no ser relevantes y tampoco tengo datos.

Si yo uso una consulta sin agrupar:

```
SELECT * 
from movimiento 
left join ticket on movimiento.idticket=ticket.idticket 
WHERE 
cajero=333 AND sesion=1
```

Obtengo dos filas, cada una con la info del movimiento y con el dato del ticket asociado:

```
idmov   tipomov     importe     idticket    idcliente   idsesion    fecha   idticket    fecha   total   vuelto  hora    idtipocomp  idc     cae     fechavto    cajero  sesion  pago
1   1   123.45  1   1   1   2020-09-07 12:10:18     1   fecha   145.89  0   hora    1   123     cae     2020-09-07  333     1   pago
2   2   22.44   1   1   1   2020-09-07 12:10:18     1   fecha   145.89  0   hora    1   123     cae     2020-09-07  333     1   pago
```

Entendería que eso es lo que buscas. Ahora bien, nos comentas que quieres hacer el group by en el ticket. Podrías hacer un

```
SELECT ticket.*, sum(movimiento.importe)
from movimiento 
left join ticket on movimiento.idticket=ticket.idticket 
WHERE 
cajero=333 AND sesion=1
```

Y obtendrías una única fila con el ticket Y el monto total de los movimientos.

```
idticket    fecha   total   vuelto  hora    idtipocomp  idc     cae     fechavto    cajero  sesion  pago    sum(movimiento.importe)
1   fecha   145.89  0   hora    1   123     cae     2020-09-07  333     1   pago    145.89
```

Lo raro es: **ya tienes ese valor en la fila total del ticket** porque la normalización no está muy bien que digamos (o bueh, necesitas tener el dato ahí por algún requerimiento no funcional). Por eso no es claro por qué dices que *quieres agrupar por ticket Y mostrar todos los movimientos*. Es excluyente.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y perdona si no me expreso bien. Yo tengo una ventana con el resumen de caja. Entonces muestro todos los movimientos del dia o de la sesion. Y quiero mostrar en una misma fila el monto abonado con la tarjeta y en efectivo.. Es decir. los dos movimientos de un mismo ticket. Porque de la otra forma usa 2 lineas de la tabla. Y quizas tenes razon.. La tabla cliente y comprobante hacen que no aparezcan los dos resultados. Comprobante sirve para el tipo de boleta y cliente es el compradir en cuestion

Comment: @Caruso Vale, entender bien el problema siempre es parte de una buena solución, no hay lío. La pregunta es: ¿qué pasa si hay tres movimientos? ¿si reparten una cuenta entre cinco o diez tarjetas como en un restaurante? Se volvería una única fila con muchísimas columnas. ¿Seguro que eso es lo que buscas? O tal vez valga la pena revisar cómo presentas la información en tu interfaz? Siempre se agradece tener la menor cantidad de consultas posible peeero pues... también hay un tradeoff en lo usable del resultset, que toque volver a procesarlo más arriba en otra capa

Comment: Ok.. Con tarjeta me refiero a tarjeta de credito o debito.. Un mismo ticket puede ser pagado en parte con tarjeta y el resto en efectivo. No hay otra columna que agregar. Simplemente quiero mostrar cuanto se pago con tarjeta y cuanto efectivo en un mismo ticket.

Comment: Cada ticket puedee tener hasta 2 movimientos. Si el cliente paga todo en efectivo es solo 1 registro de movimiento.Entendes?